# How to clone a TextView?

Tags: android

Say I have a textview that I got from xml.

```
final View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  

final TextView tvPop = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvKeyPop);
```

But I want to have multiple **tvPop** 's, how should I clone them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
TextView cloned = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
cloned.setText(tvPop.getText());
cloned.setLayoutParams(tvPop.getLayoutParams());
...
cloned.setWhateverFieldYouNeedToBeCloned(tvPop().getWhateverFieldYouNeedToBeCloned());
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: is there a convenient way?

Comment: Really old thread, but just to edit. You should pass an Activity Context rather than application context to prevent leaks.